# Error: Incompatible types: 'Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGridOption' and 'DBGridEh.TDBGridOption'

Tags: delphi

Before adding DBGridEh component everything worked fine. After adding I get compilation error:

> Incompatible types: 'Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGridOption' and
> 'DBGridEh.TDBGridOption'

`Form1.DBGrid1.Options:=Form1.DBGrid1.Options -[dgEditing,dgAlwaysShowSelection];`

How to correct this code?

Comment: Either change the `uses` clause order, or qualify the constants like `Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGridOption.dgEditing`.